# List Rules in Zend_ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-acl

I'm using zend_acl to manage ACL lists in my web application.
To be able to show a 'Manage Permissions' Dialogue I need a possibility to get defined rules for the following combinations:
- rules set for a specific role on a specific resource
- all rules that have been set for roles on a specific resource (who has which rights on this)
- all rules that have been set for a specific role on any resource (which rights does the role have)
To be able to display a complete list there must always be an additional list with rules that have been inherited from parent roles/resources.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all the roles and the resources this way

```
$acl = new Application_Model_Acl();
$acl->getRegisteredRoles(); // roles instances
$acl->getRoles(); //array
$acl->getResources(); //array
```

I think you have to extend Zend_Acl for retrieve the "registered resources per role".

If the project is so "extended", usually, I generate the Acl dinamically from database, but I created a Zend_Acl extension by my side

Comment: Just a head's up, getRegisteredRoles has been deprecated since version 1.10, getRoles is it's replacement.

Comment: Thank you MiPnamic, I'll do it like this

Answer (score 0):

For overview we created a table where horizontally are resources, vertcally roles (received as MiPnamic suggested). And in the body of the table there are zeros a ones (allowed, denied). It works fine.